# How to prevent HTML5 crashing to Adobe Flash?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, flash-player, html5

After loading the video and letting the video remain paused for an hour or more, I unpause the video and then it crashes after a few seconds. It crashes as a HTML5 player and resorts to Adobe Flash player.

I am using version 42.0.2292.0 canary (64-bit) and 40.0.2214.94 of the stable release. This occurs in both of the releases. Windows 7 OS.

Comment: Are you talking about a YouTube video? It's not clear from your description what you're actually trying.

Comment: Does it still occur if you disallow drive spin down , AKA in win7 as "turn off hard disk" in the power options. Mentioned because some players will allow time for a hard drive to spin back up and respond, and some do not handle that well.

Comment: I do have the drive to not spin down at any time at the time of crashing. Yes, I am talking about a YouTube video.

Comment: You should ask google to fix their lame video player, there's not much you can do on your end unfortunately.

Comment: Even so, am I not able to prevent it from switching to Adobe Flash and just reload HTML5?